# WINAPI LISTBOX scroll down

Tags: winapi, listbox, scroll

I'm creating my own program in WINAPI. I've got one problem.

I created a listbox with `WS_VSCROLL` style.

Everything is ok, but if I fill the listbox with strings the last strings are "invisible".

I must to scroll down list and then I can see the strings.

How do I automatically scroll down the listbox, using the mouse, to show the last string?

You know, I wrote chatBox. Every chatbox, which I know, has got this function:

```
hListaChatu = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME, "LISTBOX", NULL,
WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER|WS_VSCROLL,  rect_okna_glownego.right - 320,
rect_okna_glownego.top, 300, rect_edit_text.top - 25 , hwnd, NULL,
hInstance, NULL );
```

Comment: What do you mean "automatically scroll down the listbox, using the mouse"?

Comment: I mean that if I fill list, for looking new elements I have to scroll down. If you write eg. on Facebook older messages are hidden, but actually are show. I wanna autoscroll list, when I send new string.

Comment: You can send the listbox `WM_SCROLL` messages to make it scroll, if that's what you mean.

Comment: How I can "send" it?

Comment: SendMessage or PostMessage are the usual ways...

Comment: I wrote: SendMessage( hListaChatu, WM_SCROLL, 0,0);, but it's not correct...

Comment: Did you check the docs for the `WM_VSCROLL` message?

Comment: How check the docs? Sorry but I'm new in WinAPi

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks. But how I can do it programally? Why it: SendMessage( hListaChatu, WM_SCROLL, 0,0);  doesn't work. I send messages to list with strings. When I put 20 string I don't se 21., 22. 23. etc. strings. If I wanna see 22. string I must scroll down using mouse. How I can scroll down in code, when I put 20 string?

Comment: Read the docs for the WM_VSCROLL message to work out what values to send it. You won't get very far programming WinAPI if you don't read the docs for the functions and messages you're using.

Comment: Thanks man. I did it :D It's work!!!! Happy New Year!